# Wakanda 2 - transitioning a WAF application

Tags: wakanda, web-application-firewall

After restructuring my Solution/Project files, converting my login listener out of required.js and into a module (setLoginManager), and ensuring that API changes were addressed ... I am getting the following error showing up at the browser level when the initial login page is being displayed.

Would appreciate any guidance ... appears to be a WAF related issue not related to my application>

[image]

Comment: You get a `401 (Not Authorized)` when getting the catalog description. `ds.addToCalalog` cannot work if the app cannot gather the catalog description.
How is working the url `https://127.0.0.1:8091/rest/$catalog/$all/` ?

Comment: The command generating the error is something internal to Wakanda, as I do not issue any commands to access the catalog.  This application uses web components for a desktop web application.  It is trying to display a web component that includes the logon widgets (ID, Pwd, button) at the time that this occurs.

Comment: Yep, and the internal code is sending a request to `$catalog/$all/` which is failing. Can you confirme by requesting `https://127.0.0.1:8091/rest/$catalog/$all/` alone ? This issue could be related to wrong read/describe database permissions which have changed in `v2`.

Comment: I will do this as soon as I have access to the system early this evening.  I understand that you want me to simply issue the above URL from the browser.  Results to follow.

Comment: In running the above request, I get a similar message as what I see in the server log:

Comment: {"__ERROR":[{"message":"No permission to describe the YtdCatReport datastore class","componentSignature":"dbmg","errCode":1609}]}

Comment: Great, please update your question with this details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error. You do not have `describe` permission for the `YtdCatReport` dataclass.

In `v1`, when you have `read` permission on a dataclass, it gets automatically the `describe` permission. It is fixed in `v2` version. Now you have to explicitly set both permissions.

Add `describe` permission on the `YtdCatReport` dataclass as you did for `read`.